# Can JSX like syntax be achieved in Javascript with minimum functionalities?

Tags: javascript, jsx

I want to know, if it's possible to write all valid html tags inside a Javascript function such that the syntax looks like JSX as per as possible, or simply a way such that the html markup didn't require to write in strings ? For example lets imagine of a function body() which will do something like this :

```
body(`
 <h1>I am JavaScript</h1>
`);
```

Output :

```
 <h1>I am JavaScript</h1>
```

I am imagining if the body function could be updated such that it can be performed something like this :

```
body( 
 return <h1>I am nearly alike JSX</h1>
);
```

Output :

```
 <h1>I am nearly alike JSX</h1>
```

Is this type of syntax can only be achieved by JSX ? Can it be done with some code in Javascript ? Or its not possible ? I am curious to know ? I know JSX supports custom tags but for now lets leave that and focus on all valid tags !

Thanks In Advance

Comment: is your question  "can we render html as jsx ? "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't support IE11 (or transpile your code anyways), you can get something like that with [tagged template literals](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_template-literals.html#_tagged-template-literals):

```js
function myjsx(html, ...args) {
  return html.slice(1).reduce((str, elem, i) => str + args[i] + elem, html[0]);
}

var hello = 'Hello';
var world = 'Arcanadian Arc';
document.body.innerHTML = myjsx`<h1>${hello} ${world}!</h1>`;
```

There's even a library that does that: [t7.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/t7). And there's a part of the JSX specification draft on why they don't do that: [Why not template literals](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/#why-not-template-literals).